# Custom WPF Control no longer visible after DevExpress control upgrade

Tags: wpf, controls, devexpress

**Context**
I have written a TreeList/TreeGrid (i.e. tree with columns) control that inherits the TreeView control. I reference this control in two different DLL's and style it differently in each of them. DLL 'A' has the TreeList control in it, and DLL 'B' references DLL 'A' for the TreeList control.

**Problem**
I've just upgraded my application to use the new DevExpress WPF controls (v2010.2). Ever since I upgraded, the TreeList control in DLL 'B' is no longer visible and the control in DLL 'A' is visible and working fine. I've used Snoop to see whether the control is actually there and it is, and the IsVisible property is true.

**Current Theory**
In the DevExpress update they've started to theme the TreeView control which they didn't do in the previous version. So I'm guessing that there is some resource dictionary mix up, but I'm no expert so don't really know where to start debugging. Any pointer as to where to begin looking would really be appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved this issue now. It turns out that I had explicitly defined the control template for a tree view in DLL 'A' but not in its resource dictionary so DLL 'B' couldn't reference it. So before the DevExpress upgrade it would have picked up the TreeView style from some WPF DLL somewhere which is now not available, or something like that....